# Reducing column size and data type in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table adv(id(TEXT),index(TEXT) ) which I need to change it as follows

```
ALTER TABLE adv
  MODIFY COLUMN id VARCHAR(80),
  MODIFY COLUMN index INT(11);
```

will this preserve all the data in the above columns assuming that they are less then 80 chars for id and a number for index?

Comment: You should consider adding `NOT NULL` and `UNSIGNED` if appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will. When there's no load on the table, I would suggest following procedure though. Not only can you double-check if everything is okay, it probably is also faster.

```
CREATE TABLE new_adv LIKE adv;

ALTER TABLE new_adv
  MODIFY COLUMN id VARCHAR(80),
  MODIFY COLUMN index INT(11);

INSERT INTO new_adv SELECT * FROM adv;

RENAME adv TO old_adv, new_adv TO adv;
/*when everything is okay...*/
DROP TABLE old_adv;
```

And by the way, it's a good idea not to use keywords like `index` for column names. You might want to change that, too. And if it's just for the benefit of not having to use backticks all the time when you use this column.

Comment: what will be lost?

Comment: i have issued the command in question can i stop it now?

Comment: Nothing will be lost, it should say "yes, it will preserve all data". Which command have you executed, and why would you want to stop it?

Comment: so the existing cols will be cast to varchar and int from TEXT ? if i use the command in question

Comment: Cast if you want, haven't tried it but assumed that MySQL implicitly converts the values.

Comment: so the existing cols will be cast to varchar and int from TEXT ? if i use the command in question

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? Is it a live system you're working on? I personally try almost everything on a dev system first.

Comment: @db101 So, did it work out for you?